# What is Safe base API URL for Gnosis Chain?

Tags: gnosis-safe, api, safe, gnosis-chain

What is Safe base API URL for Gnosis Chain?

Can't find any in the docs

Both
https://safe-transaction-xdai.safe.global
https://safe-transaction-gnosis.safe.global
don't work

Answer (score 0):

Do check the docs: https://safe-transaction-gnosis-chain.safe.global/

The official base url is listed as [ Base URL: safe-transaction-gnosis-chain.safe.global/api ]